# What are the architectural patterns used in Mobile applications (other than MVC)?

Tags: mobile, architecture

MVC is the most common architectural pattern used for developing Mobile apps.

Please share your experience on applying other architectural patters, like Multitier architecture in mobile apps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many derivative of MVC like MVW, MVVM etc and other patterns at server side like Repository and UoW are being used for mobile apps.

To start with, here is the Mobile Architecture Guide from Microsoft:
http://robtiffany.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Mobile_Architecture_Guide_v1.1.pdf

Additionally below links would help you a lot:
[Mobile Development Architecture & Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090791/mobile-development-architecture-design-patterns)
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Praveen, Thanks for shearing these resource. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

For iOS devs, this is an excellent article depicting architectural patterns.

https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52#.gzhgc4u6p

Answer (score 0):

For android developers, this are sample apps for different architecture patterns like mvp, clean, mvvm, etc: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture